# PHP keep checkbox checked after submitting form

Tags: php, html

Hi all i have a contact form and captcha is there. i want keep the check is checked after submitting the form. I posted the textbox values and it showing correctly but checkbox is not working. here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action = "" name="frmSubmit" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="txtCheck" value="<?php echo $_POST['txtCheck'];?>"  /><br />
<label>Name</label><br />
<input type="text" name="txtName" id="NameTextBox" value="<?php echo $_POST['txtName']; ?>" />
<br />
<label>E Mail</label><br />
 <input type="text" name="txtEmail" id="EmailTextBox" value="<?php  echo $_POST['txtEmail'];?>" />
 <input name="BtnSubmit" type="submit" onclick="MM_validateForm('NameTextBox','','R','EmailTextBox','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" value="Send" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How to keep check box after submitting the form.?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

change

```
<input type="checkbox" name="txtCheck" value="<?php echo $_POST['txtCheck'];?>"  /><br />
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" name="txtCheck" value="your value" <?php if(isset($_POST['txtCheck'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  /><br />
```

this will keep checkbox checked..

Comment: What if the checkbox is within an array? `name="txtCheck[]"`

Comment: `<?php if (in_array("your_value", $_POST['txtCheck'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>`

Comment: thanks what happens if i do not want to keep all of them selected in the array. only the one that were selected

Answer (score 1):

If the submitted value is not empty, then add the `checked="checked"` attribute to the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="txtCheck" value="1" <?php if (!empty($_POST['txtCheck'])): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> />
```

You can however leave the `value` attribute intact.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="txtCheck" <?php if($_POST['txtCheck']>0){ ?>checked="checked" <? }?> />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$checked = "";
if ($_POST['txtCheck']) {
  $checked = "checked";
  // May need to be "checked='checked'" for xhtml
}
<input type="checkbox" name="txtCheck" <?php echo $checked;?>  /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

By apply ternary condition in checkbox tag field we can set whether this is checked or not on form submission

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="nofollow" <?=isset($_POST['nofollow'])?"checked":''; ?> >
```