# How to Keep Checkbox checked when summon with foreach

Tags: php, html

i have checkbox summon with forearch like this

```
foreach( $orderarray as $key => $cucian )
{
        switch ($cucian['tipe']) {

    case 'cuci dan setrika':
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='cuci' /> Cuci";
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='setrika' /> Setrika";

           break;

          case 'setrika':
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='cuci' disabled /> Cuci";
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='setrika' /> Setrika";

           break;
 }       
}
```

i have read this link :
[PHP keep checkbox checked after submitting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541419/php-keep-checkbox-checked-after-submitting-form)

and add this

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['setrika'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>
```

but why after submitting form , all checkbox with name 'setrika' is checked

any method to solve my problem ?

thanks in advance

Comment: It is a good idea to translate your labels etc into English to make them meaningful to the International reader group. You'll get more, and faster, help that way.

Answer (score 0):

Either you give different names to your checkboxes, or use the array notation:

```
 <input type='checkbox' name='setrika[]'>
```

Notice the `[]` brackets: you'll have to iterate over `$_POST['setrika']`, which will be an array:

```
 $_POST['setrika'][$n]
```

grants you access to the `$n`-th position of your array.