# How can I keep the checkbox checked after I submit a form using PHP?

Tags: php, checkbox

I'm trying to get a value from post array then store it in a variable then use the value to keep the checkbox selected.  Here's what I'm trying:

I have this line above the foreach:

```
    <input type='checkbox' name='$plyrMtchResult 'value=''>$plyrMtchResult</input>  //This line works fine

 //then when I submit the form the foreach loop runs here.

  foreach($_POST as $value => $key)
        {

                $post_Value= str_replace("_", " ", $value);

                "<input type='checkbox' name='$post_Value' value='post_valuebValue' checked='checked'>$post_valuebValue</input>";

        }
```

My issue seems similar to what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541419/php-keep-checkbox-checked-after-submitting-form) but mine is not working.

How can I keep the checkbox checked after I submit the form.

Comment: are you echoing out that input element on the page somewhere?  Something is missing from your code sample here

Comment: I am confused why you have that foreach loop.  Are you trying to print as many checkboxes on the page as you have $_POST variables?  Also, in general your `$value => $key` is backwards.  When you referencing `$value` in your `str_replace` you are actually referencing the key of your $_POST array

Comment: Yes I'm trying to print as many checkboxes as there are $_POST variables.  I'll change the value->key part.

Comment: I don't want to echo a new checkbox tag.  I want to manipulate the one that's already displayed with the code that's above the loop.

Comment: @CloudyKooper How do you want to manipulate it if it is already printed it?! Also show us your entire code and please explain a bit more what your goal is

Comment: @CloudyKooper You know that you have also other older posts where you didn't accepted a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type='checkbox' name='$post_Value'     value='post_valuebValue'    checked='checked'>$post_valuebValue</input>
```

I would do something like this please forgive any syntax errors in doing this on my phone

```
<input type='checkbox' name='$post_Value' value='post_valuebValue' <?pho if ($postvalue = checked){echo 'checked='checked'}?>'>$post_valuebValue</input>";
```

Echo checked html into field to keep it checked

Answer (score 0):

Your code rather seems confusing, but if I am understanding you correctly, you need something like this

`<input type='checkbox' name='$plyrMtchResult 'value='' <?php echo (isset($_POST['$plyMtchResult'])?'checked':''); ?> >$plyrMtchResult</input>`

You don't need to run foreach loop, if you just want to set checked value for already existing checkbox elements.