# maintain checkbox which were checked after submit

Tags: php, forms, post, checkbox, checked

I know there's "[PHP keep checkbox checked after submitting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541419/php-keep-checkbox-checked-after-submitting-form)" on here, but that thread does not solve my problem, because I have multiple checkbox, what I need is when you check a checkbox, this stay checked after submit.

At the moment with this code nothing happens, I tried another way but when I check "id7" checkbox, all the checkbox get checked.

I have to know which checkbox was checked by the id that I give it, but I do not know how.

```
while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    echo utf8_encode("
            <tr>
              <td>
                ".$fila['title']."
              </td>
              ");?>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checklist[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($fila['id']); ?>" <?php if(isset($_POST['checklist[]']) && is_array($_POST['checklist[]']) && in_array('$fila', $_POST['checklist[]'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
              </td>
              <?php 
            }
          }
       ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the value of checkbox is `$fila['id']` so when you are checking, use `$fila['id']` instead of `$fila`. Also, when PHP receive array input fields with `[]` in their names the `[]` will be removed so that the correct POST variable is `$_POST['checklist']`.

Try changing this line:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($fila['id']); ?>" <?php if(isset($_POST['checklist[]']) && is_array($_POST['checklist[]']) && in_array('$fila', $_POST['checklist[]'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($fila['id']); ?>" <?php if(isset($_POST['checklist']) && is_array($_POST['checklist']) && in_array($fila['id'], $_POST['checklist'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
```

Comment: Dude rly thx, but when I checked refresh the page does not hold up, you know why?

Answer (score 0):

"name" is like a variable name - by using checklist[] you're defining an array as the variable. 
Why not just name each checkbox properly? When the form is submitted, use the contents of $_POST to set each variable into the user's $_SESSION.

If the page is refreshed, use the values from $_SESSION to determine if the checkbox should be ticked. Something like (untested):

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" 
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['bike_checked']) echo 'checked'; ?>> I have a bike<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" 
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['car_checked']) echo 'checked'; ?>> I have a car<br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Nop, with $_SESSION doesnt do anything, and that's what i rly need, that keep checked if i refresh  the page

Comment: You either mean 2 things - either #1 you're not starting the page with session_start(); so the values are not getting stored properly into the session array or #2 you really want to handle this via Javascript (if you're looking for the tick->then F5 - but that wouldn't make sense if I was trying to reload the page back to fresh).