# How to retain the selected boxes checked in a foreachloop after submit

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

How do i retain the selected boxes selected/checked after submit...

```
        <td>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
         <label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">
         <input type="checkbox" name="total_odds[]" id="total odds" value="<?php echo $game->odds; ?>" autocomplete="off"> <?php echo $game->odds; ?>
        </label>
        </div>
        </td>

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    if(empty($_POST["total_odds"])){
    $main_odds_error = "<div class='error-msg'>You have not selected any odds ☺</div>";
    }else{
    $main_odds      = $_POST["total_odds"];
    $total = 1;
    if(!empty($main_odds)){
        foreach ($main_odds as $final_odd){
                $total   = $total * $final_odd;
        }
    }
    $count_main_odd = count($main_odds);
    $total_odds = number_format($total, 2); 
}
}
```

I want it to retain whatever number odd was selected...

Comment: just add your php code before html then you will have all total_odds values in html which you can to select checkbox.

Comment: Not sure what the question is. Is it not working? What error, if any, are you getting?

Comment: @Akhilesh   my code is working fine... i just want it a little more dynamic... anytime i click the submit button, the checkbox clears off... i want it to remember what i clicked after submitting

Comment: @NawedKhan my code is working fine... i just want it a little more dynamic... anytime i click the submit button, the checkbox clears off... i want it to remember what i clicked after submitting

Comment: thats what i am saying you are posting those values that means those values will be available to you so all you need to do is check the value of checkbox with current posted value and then set the property `checked=cheked` for those checkboxes

Comment: @Akhilesh i want the checkboxes remain checked after submit

Comment: this is what i was saying and hopefully this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541419/php-keep-checkbox-checked-after-submitting-form