# How to continue keeping the checkbox in checked position after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a little trouble with my PHP, js code. When I submit form page is reloading but input checkbox isn't in checked mode, but I need is.

I think maybe I need to get parameter from URL and then compare it with the DOM element and after that set checked mode for input?

**PHP code:**

```
if(isset($_GET['user_id'])) {

    try {
        $PDO_connection = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $opt);

        $queryForUserInfo = "SELECT position, dateOfBirth, rank, tellNumber, worker_id
                                               FROM workers
                                               WHERE user_id = :id";

        $sth = $PDO_connection->prepare($queryForUserInfo);
        $sth->bindParam(":id", $_GET['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->execute();
        $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $queryForComeAndReturnUserInfo = "SELECT date_come, date_return
                                      FROM outside_records 
                                      WHERE worker_id = {$result[0]['worker_id']}
                                      ORDER BY date_return DESC";

        $sth1 = $PDO_connection->prepare($queryForComeAndReturnUserInfo);
        $sth1->bindParam(":id", $_GET['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth1->execute();
        $outsideSchedule = $sth1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    } catch (PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    };
}

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="get" id="listOfUsers_form">

    <!--just for getting id to make db query-->
    <?php foreach ($AllUsers as $user):?>
        <tr class='usersList'>
            <td><input type='checkbox' name='user_id' value='<?php if(isset($user)){echo $user['user_id'];}?>'></td>
            <td><?php echo $user['name'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user['surname'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user['position'];?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</form>
```

**js code:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    let row = $('#colorful_row').html();

    if(row == "Відсутній на робочому місті") {
        $("#status").css("background-color", "red");
    } else if (row == "На робочому місці") {
        $("#status").css("background-color", "lightgreen");
    } else  {
        $("#status").css("background-color", "white");
    }

    $(".usersList td input:checkbox").on("change", function(){
        $(this.attr("checked", "checked"));
        $("#listOfUsers_form").submit();

    });
});

</script>
```

Thanks, everybody

Comment: Would it solve your issue to submit the form with AJAX to a different URL and then NOT refresh the page? That way the page state will stay the same.

Comment: I don`t want to use AJAX

Comment: In that case, you can potentially use something like `sessionStorage` to save the state of your page and refresh it when your page loads again. I would recommend possibly storing a JSON representation of the state of the page - if your page is called '/app/page', you can do `sessionStorage.setItem('/app/page', jsonString)` to set the JSON when your checkboxes update, and then when your page loads check for JSON previously set by using `sessionStorage.getItem('/app/page')`

Comment: The topic is too broad to give you the full answer, hopefully you can take that advice and work from there.

Comment: Try to store selected checkbox values in `localStorage`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP keep checkbox checked after submitting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541419/php-keep-checkbox-checked-after-submitting-form)

Comment: No, in my case name in url will always present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `localStorage`

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zv8q7bnd/3/)**

For localstorage saved the boolean value as string .That why we compare with `localStorage.getItem("box") == 'true'`

```
$('input').prop('checked', localStorage.getItem("box") == 'true')

$('input').on('change', function() {
  window.localStorage.setItem($(this).attr('name'), Boolean($(this).is(':checked')))
})
```

[image]