# how to keep correct checkbox value check array after submit/document.form[0] submit or refresh page SOLVED

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<script>
function refreshPage()
{
  document.forms[0].submit();
}    
</script>
<?php
 foreach($values as $value)
  {
  ?>
   <input type = "checkbox" name = "food[]" value = "<?php echo($value['dinner']);?>">
  <?php 
       } 
    ?>



<button name = "pass" onClick = "refreshPage()">refresh</button>
```

so I have n amount of check box (depending on how many values user has)I want to keep them the check box check after the page refresh (by clicking on  refresh button). I tried searching and saw similar form but the answer did not work for me.

For example the most popular answer was:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="txtCheck" value="your value"
 <?php if(isset($_POST['txtCheck']))
 echo "checked='checked'"; ?> 
 /><br />
```

this had two problem after i hit the refresh button value would not be save until i hit it twice to save(i want it to save after one click. Also sometime it save after one click but if i hit the refresh 3 time values are lost I want it to be save no matter how many time user refresh)

the second problem was it check all of the box would be check. I only want to keep the one user has check to be save.

I looked at various other possible solution but nothing worked

so if you could please help much would be appreciated. Also I need the value to be kept. I am using the checkbox value somewhere else

Edit something like this but for my array food[]. This only works for invidiual values

```
<input type="checkbox" name="small" class="checkbox" <?php if 
 ($_POST['small']) echo 'checked'; ?> /> Small
```

Comment: The question is: why do you still want the form displayed when it is submitted?\

Comment: i have more info/code below that is display after the user submit it. The info display base on what the user select that is why i want the form to be display

Comment: Disadvantage of submitting to the same page is you have to rebuild the whole page including the form again, testing the values to see what to display. My suggestion: read on how to post the form with Ajax. After succes you can remove the submitbutton from the first form and add your info to the same page. It's a bit of work but worth while the time.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I might try that in the future. But as of this moment I just need to figure it out using php/vanilla javascript/html. It's been bothering me for a while. So if you know how to do it or find a good solution please lmk

Comment: check edit haha found something close

Comment: I found the answer in this post to those who are still looking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541419/php-keep-checkbox-checked-after-submitting-form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP keep checkbox checked after submitting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541419/php-keep-checkbox-checked-after-submitting-form)